# RNA-seq differential expression with DESeq2: p-value and FC "limits"

Tags: r, p-value, bioinformatics

I have used `DESeq2` package (version 1.12.3 with R 3.3.1) to identify differentially expressed (DE) genes between two groups of cell culture samples, 3 treated and 3 controls.

Considering adjusted pvalue<0.01 as cut-off, there are about 2500 DE genes. Some genes have very high fold changes (i.e. over 20 genes with `log2(FC)>5` and the top one with `log2(FC)=9.5`). Also, some (n=16) adjusted p-values are 0.

I have a few questions:

1. I guess the 0 pvalues are shown as zero because they are lower than the smallest representable value with the computer. Is that correct? How much is this value?
2. clustering and PCA plot of the samples show that treated and control samples are clearly separated. However I am still surprised by the extremely high fold changes and small p-values, compared with other datasets I have seen. From the analysis point of view, is there a way to understand whether there is some 'bias' in the data, such as the replicates not being truly independent?

Comment: Be aware that #1 is about how R works & isn't really on topic here. It may not get an answer.

Comment: would it be better to post on another forum?

Comment: Yes, you are right it is an R question but also looking for a statistical confirmation to the fact that theoretically a statistical test performed on a continuous variable should never give pvalue=0 so it must be a computer-related issue, correct?

Comment: Your question overall should be fine here. & yes, there isn't really a p=0.0 to infinite decimal places, but computers only do finite arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably these p-values are different from 0, but you numbers are only shown up to a certain precision. Try changing these setting through

   ```
   options(digits=20)
   ```

A P-value can never be exactly zero for a properly stated null hypothesis. You can view your machine's precision with

```
    .Machine$double.eps
```

2. With so few replicates (as alwyas in RNA-Seq, I know) this is very hard to ascertain. The high fold changes and corresponding p-values are most likely due to outliers, which have a very strong influence of course on the estimate of the fold change when $n_1 = n_2 = 3$. My guess is that due to the shrinking of the overdispersion estimates towards the mean-dispersion trend, the estimate of the fold-change sky-rockets, but not the estimate of the fold change and as a result they are still declared significant